# changed page title in hook _ menu section of Drupal module but no change seen on page

Tags: drupal, menu, module, hook, title

I changed page title in hook _ menu section of a Drupal module, re-installed, and cleared caches, but this did not change title on web page.

Finally I renamed the whole module, files, and relevant function names in files and then re-installed. This did the trick.

I suspect that there is a duplicate entry in mysql table that holds title somewhere but not sure where.

Comment: This isn't very descriptive. You modified a module but didn't say which one, or why.

Comment: it is custom data data export module to feed a legacy OE system. The name is not relevant. Generically I want to know why the module title did not change.

Answer (score 0):

The module title is coming from the module's .info file. Changing it here will change the relevant bit on the Modules page of your site.

Comment: Actually it was page title.  Caches were not being cleared, so title was not changing.